Deploy Nuxtjs site on github page
I use the https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/pages/nuxtjs.yml github actions.
My site is deployed but all assets doesn't have the baseURL
Look:
status: 200
GET /pascal-presentation-site/ HTTP/2
Host: alexisvs.github.io
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
TE: trailers

status: 404
GET /_nuxt/DgV0bi9m.js HTTP/2
Host: alexisvs.github.io
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://alexisvs.github.io/pascal-presentation-site/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: script
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
TE: trailers

All of my assets are at https://alexisvs.github.io/pascal-presentation-site/
When I modify the nuxt config as follows:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    app: {
        baseURL: '/pascal-presentation-site/',
        buildAssetsDir: '/pascal-presentation-site/_nuxt/',
    },
});

It don't take it in consideration because my github actions erase these parameters.
So I'm lost.
If you have an idea ?
I've tried using various github actions. But the documentation is superfluous when it comes to deployment. I don't understand much

Honestly, GH pages are the biggest trap ever. Just try to ship it to Netlify, Verceo, Cloudflare pages, Digital ocean, or any other better platform. Will have less config and something working well probably out of the box. Of course, if you have some bundler misconfiguration, that's not really a platform issue. Does the project work well if you build it locally?

GitHub Pages is really a rough service. Consider use modern platforms instead

This is just to show the progress of my development. For production, I'll be using a different host.

Still, just a pain. Netlify takes what: 60s of setup to have something working. Otherwise, ship a .zip nightly rather than trying to setup some GH actions etc..
